# print text between pipes

Tags: bash

I have a text file with ids as below

```
ref|XP_029641976.1|
ref|XP_014779594.1|
gb|KOF78315.1|
```

I wish to print only the text between pipes and I've tried this sed -n '/|/,/|/p and also tried substituting but they don't work. The string in front of the first pipe varies. Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: i'd go for awk: `awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}; {print $2}'` that's the (almost) exact line of the manual for field separators (!)

Comment: `cut -d \| -f2 file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can get text **between** pipes with `sed` regexp like this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "ref|XP_029641976.1|
ref|XP_014779594.1|
gb|KOF78315.1|" | sed -E "s:.*\|(.*?)\|:\1:g"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, awk is a good candidate for this:

```
awk -F'|' '{ print $2 }' file
```

Specify the field delimiter with -F and then print the second pipe delimited field with $2